# Convergence criterion for nonnegative sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came across a problem recently which had the following (more or less unrelated) corollary:

Suppose $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are sequences of nonnegative real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$ and $\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{1+b_n}\le a_n$ for all $n$. Then $b_n$ converges.

I couldn't see any obvious way to prove this directly, and have even had doubts about whether it is true. I also cannot come up with a counterexample. What do you think?

EDIT: Using a few ideas from the answers so far (most notably Kay K's second answer), I have made a little more progress. The condition implies $1+b_{n+1}\le(1+a_n)(1+b_n)$, from which we inductively deduce that

$$ 1+b_{n+1}\le\left(\prod_{k=1}^n(1+a_k)\right)(1+b_1)\le\left(\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1+a_k)\right)(1+b_1)<\infty,$$

where we know the infinite product converges since $\sum a_n<\infty$. This gives us that the sequence is bounded. If $1+b_n\le M$ for all $n$, then for all $n$ such that $b_{n+1}\ge b_n$ we have

$$|b_{n+1}-b_n|\le Ma_n.$$

My idea now is to prove either a similar inequality in the case where $b_{n+1}<b_n$, or else prove there are at most finitely many such $n$. This would prove the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(b_{n+1}-b_n)$ which would complete the proof. Finish it off if you can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative, probably better solution:

Define $m_n:=\frac{1+b_n}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots(1+a_{n-1})}$. Then

$$0\le m_{n+1}\le\frac1{\prod_{k=1}^n(1+a_k)}(1+a_n)(1+b_n)=m_n,$$

so $(m_n)$ is a bounded and monotone sequence and hence $m_n\to m$. It follows that

$$b_n\to m\prod_{k=1}^\infty(1+a_k)-1,$$

where the infinite product is finite since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n<\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Different solution:

\begin{align}
\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{1+b_n}&\le a_n\\
b_{n+1}&\le (1+b_n)a_n+b_n=(1+b_n)(1+a_n)-1\\
b_{2}+1&\le (1+b_1)(1+a_1)\\
b_{3}+1&\le (1+b_2)(1+a_2)\le(1+b_1)(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\\
b_{4}+1&\le (1+b_3)(1+a_3)\le(1+b_1)(1+a_1)(1+a_2)(1+a_3)\\
\vdots\\
b_{n+1}+1&\le (1+b_1)\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k)\right)\\
\end{align}
By AM-GM,
\begin{align}
\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k)\right)^{\frac1n}&\le\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k)}{n}\\
\therefore b_{n+1}+1&\le (1+b_1)\left(\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k)}{n}\right)^n\\
&=(1+b_1)\left(1+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}{n}\right)^n\\
\lim_{n\to\infty} b_{n}&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((1+b_1)\left(1+\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k}{n}\right)^n-1\right)\\
&=(1+b_1)e^{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\right)}-1\\
&=(1+b_1)e^S-1\\
\end{align}

where $S=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$. Therefore $b_n$ is upper bounded.

Comment: This isn't quite correct - once you deduce $1+b_{n+1}\le(1+b_1)\prod_{k=1}^n(1+a_k)$ you may conclude that $(b_n)$ is bounded, but this is not sufficient.

Comment: I probably should have pointed out that even though your proof is not complete, it is still very useful!

Comment: Maybe I wrote too modestly, but actually I showed you not only that $b_n$ is bounded but also to what value it converges too. As you said $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ converges, it's limit value is known. Let's call is $S$, then $b_n$ converges to $(1+b_1)e^S-1$. I'll rewrite the last line.

Comment: No, because you have only shown $b_{n+1}\le(1+b_1)(1+\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n)^n$. There isn't equality.

Comment: Yeah, I was confused with myself. You're right, I only showed what the upper bound is.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{1+b_n}\le a_n$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{1+b_n}\le \sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n<\infty\tag{1}$$
Assume $f(x):\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$
$$f(n)=b_n$$
Then $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{1+b_n}$ converges if and only if the below integral converges. (I know I may need to be more rigorous here, especially on the $f'(x)$, but I don't know how. Please teach me.)
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{f'(x)}{1+f(x)}dx\tag{2}$$
From (1), we know that the series converges so the integral converges. Integrating (2), we get
$$\left[\ln(1+f(x))\right]_1^\infty=\ln(1+f(\infty))-\ln(1+f(1))<\infty$$
Therefore
$$f(\infty)<\infty$$
$$\therefore \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n < \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible start.

Since
$\frac{b_{n+1}-b_n}{1+b_n}
\le a_n
$,

$\begin{array}\\
b_{n+1}
&\le b_n+(1+b_n)a_n\\
&= b_n(1+a_n)+a_n\\
&\le (b_{n-1}(1+a_{n-1})+a_{n-1})(1+a_n)+a_n\\
&= b_{n-1}(1+a_{n-1})(1+a_n)+a_{n-1}(1+a_n)+a_n\\
&= b_{n-1}(1+a_{n-1})(1+a_n)+a_na_{n-1}+a_n+a_{n-1}\\
&\le (b_{n-2}(1+a_{n-2})+a_{n-2})(1+a_{n-1})(1+a_n)+a_na_{n-1}+a_n+a_{n-1}\\
&= b_{n-2}(1+a_{n-2})(1+a_{n-1})(1+a_n)+a_{n-2}(1+a_{n-1})(1+a_n)+a_na_{n-1}+a_n+a_{n-1}\\
&= b_{n-2}(1+a_{n-2})(1+a_{n-1})(1+a_n)+a_{n-2}(a_{n-1}+a_n+a_{n-1}a_n)+a_na_{n-1}+a_n+a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}\\
\end{array}
$.

Of these terms,
the terms like
$(1+a_{n-2})(1+a_{n-1})(1+a_n)$
and
$a_n+a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$,
which will becomes
$(1+a_{n-k})...(1+a_{n-1})(1+a_n)$
and
$a_n+a_{n-1}+...+a_{n-k}$,
will converge
because
$\sum a_n$
converges.

I don't know what to do 
about those middle terms,
but a clever grouping,
which I can not see,
might be able to handle them.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have a solution. First, define

$$A_N:=\sum_{\substack{b_{n+1}\ge b_n\\n\le N}}(b_{n+1}-b_n),\qquad B_N:=\sum_{\substack{b_{n+1}< b_n\\n\le N}}(b_n-b_{n+1}).$$

Then $b_{N+1}-b_1=A_N-B_N$, so it is sufficient to show $A_N$ and $B_N$ both converge.  Moreover, they are both increasing sequences, so we need only find upper bounds. From discussion above,

$$A_N\le M\sum_{\substack{b_{n+1}\ge b_n\\n\le N}}a_n\le M\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=:C<\infty$$

and

$$B_N=A_N+b_1-b_{N+1}\le C+b_1<\infty,$$

completing the proof.